# beautiful soup can not locate any table tags in given html file, although it locates other tags just as well

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to parse the given html file to find all the tables. It is actually from the api difference report for Android.

Here's the python code where I've manually inserted everything into the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

input='''
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "//www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML style="overflow:auto;">
<HEAD>
<meta name="generator" content="JDiff v1.1.0">
<!-- Generated by the JDiff Javadoc doclet -->
<!-- (http://www.jdiff.org) -->
<meta name="description" content="JDiff is a Javadoc doclet which generates an HTML report of all the packages, classes, constructors, methods, and fields which have been removed, added or changed in any way, including their documentation, when two APIs are compared.">
<meta name="keywords" content="diff, jdiff, javadiff, java diff, java difference, API difference, difference between two APIs, API diff, Javadoc, doclet">
<TITLE>
Android API Differences Report
</TITLE>
<link href="../../../../assets/android-developer-docs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../stylesheet-jdiff.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
body{overflow:auto;}
#body-content{position:relative; top:0;}
#doc-content{overflow:visible;border-left:3px solid #666;}
#side-nav{padding:0;}
#side-nav .toggle-list ul {display:block;}
#resize-packages-nav{border-bottom:3px solid #666;}
</style>
</noscript>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</HEAD>
<body class="gc-documentation">
<!-- Start of nav bar -->
<a name="top"></a>
<div id="header" style="margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;">
<div id="headerLeft">
<a href="../../../../index.html" tabindex="-1" target="_top"><img src="../../../../assets/images/bg_logo.png" alt="Android Developers" /></a>
</div>
  <div id="headerRight">
  <div id="headerLinks">
<!-- <img src="/assets/images/icon_world.jpg" alt="" /> -->
<span class="text">
<!-- &nbsp;<a href="#">English</a> | -->
<nobr><a href="//developer.android.com" target="_top">Android Developers</a> | <a href="//www.android.com" target="_top">Android.com</a></nobr>
</span>
</div>
  <div class="and-diff-id" style="margin-top:6px;margin-right:8px;">
<table class="diffspectable">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="diffspechead">API Diff Specification</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="diffspec" style="padding-top:.25em">To Level:</td>
    <td class="diffvaluenew" style="padding-top:.25em">19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="diffspec">From Level:</td>
    <td class="diffvalueold">18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="diffspec">Generated</td>
    <td class="diffvalue">2013.10.29 16:44</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div><!-- End and-diff-id -->
  <div class="and-diff-id" style="margin-right:8px;">
<table class="diffspectable">
  <tr>
    <td class="diffspec" colspan="2"><a href="jdiff_statistics.html">Statistics</a>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div> <!-- End and-diff-id -->
  </div> <!-- End headerRight -->
  </div> <!-- End header -->
<div id="body-content" xstyle="padding:12px;padding-right:18px;">
<div id="doc-content" style="position:relative;">
<div id="mainBodyFluid">
<div id="docTitleContainer">
<h1>Android&nbsp;API&nbsp;Differences&nbsp;Report</h1>
<p>This report details the changes in the core Android framework API between two <a 
href="//developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html" target="_top">API Level</a> 
specifications. It shows additions, modifications, and removals for packages, classes, methods, and fields. 
The report also includes general statistics that characterize the extent and type of the differences.</p>
<p>This report is based a comparison of the Android API specifications 
whose API Level identifiers are given in the upper-right corner of this page. It compares a 
newer "to" API to an older "from" API, noting all changes relative to the 
older API. So, for example, API elements marked as removed are no longer present in the "to" 
API specification.</p>
<p>To navigate the report, use the "Select a Diffs Index" and "Filter the Index" 
controls on the left. The report uses text formatting to indicate <em>interface names</em>, 
<a href= ><code>links to reference documentation</code></a>, and <a href= >links to change 
description</a>. The statistics are accessible from the "Statistics" link in the upper-right corner.</p>
<p>For more information about the Android framework API and SDK, 
see the <a href="//developer.android.com/index.html" target="_top">Android Developers site</a>.</p>
<p>
<a NAME="Added"></a>
<TABLE summary="Added Packages" WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
  <TH VALIGN="TOP" COLSPAN=2>Added Packages</FONT></TD>
</TH>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.graphics.pdf"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="../../../../reference/android/graphics/pdf/package-summary.html" target="_top"><code>android.graphics.pdf</code></A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.nfc.cardemulation"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="../../../../reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/package-summary.html" target="_top"><code>android.nfc.cardemulation</code></A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.print"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="../../../../reference/android/print/package-summary.html" target="_top"><code>android.print</code></A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.print.pdf"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="../../../../reference/android/print/pdf/package-summary.html" target="_top"><code>android.print.pdf</code></A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.printservice"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="../../../../reference/android/printservice/package-summary.html" target="_top"><code>android.printservice</code></A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.transition"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="../../../../reference/android/transition/package-summary.html" target="_top"><code>android.transition</code></A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
&nbsp;
<p>
<a NAME="Changed"></a>
<TABLE summary="Changed Packages" WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
  <TH VALIGN="TOP" COLSPAN=3>Changed Packages</FONT></TD>
</TH>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.html">android</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.animation"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.animation.html">android.animation</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.app"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.app.html">android.app</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.bluetooth"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.bluetooth.html">android.bluetooth</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.content"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.content.html">android.content</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.content.pm"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.content.pm.html">android.content.pm</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.content.res"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.content.res.html">android.content.res</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.database"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.database.html">android.database</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.graphics"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.graphics.html">android.graphics</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.graphics.drawable"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.graphics.drawable.html">android.graphics.drawable</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.hardware"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.hardware.html">android.hardware</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.hardware.display"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.hardware.display.html">android.hardware.display</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.location"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.location.html">android.location</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.media"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.media.html">android.media</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.media.audiofx"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.media.audiofx.html">android.media.audiofx</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.net"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.net.html">android.net</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.net.wifi"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.net.wifi.html">android.net.wifi</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.nfc"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.nfc.html">android.nfc</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.opengl"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.opengl.html">android.opengl</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.os"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.os.html">android.os</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.preference"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.preference.html">android.preference</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.provider"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.provider.html">android.provider</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.renderscript"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.renderscript.html">android.renderscript</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.security"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.security.html">android.security</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.speech.tts"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.speech.tts.html">android.speech.tts</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.telephony"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.telephony.html">android.telephony</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.test.mock"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.test.mock.html">android.test.mock</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.text.method"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.text.method.html">android.text.method</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.util"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.util.html">android.util</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.view"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.view.html">android.view</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.view.accessibility"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.view.accessibility.html">android.view.accessibility</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.view.inputmethod"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.view.inputmethod.html">android.view.inputmethod</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.webkit"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.webkit.html">android.webkit</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="android.widget"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_android.widget.html">android.widget</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.io"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.io.html">java.io</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.lang"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.lang.html">java.lang</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.lang.reflect"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.lang.reflect.html">java.lang.reflect</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.net"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.net.html">java.net</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.nio"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.nio.html">java.nio</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.nio.channels"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.nio.channels.html">java.nio.channels</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.nio.charset"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.nio.charset.html">java.nio.charset</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.sql"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.sql.html">java.sql</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.util"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.util.html">java.util</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.util.logging"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.util.logging.html">java.util.logging</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="java.util.zip"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_java.util.zip.html">java.util.zip</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="javax.crypto"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_javax.crypto.html">javax.crypto</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="javax.crypto.spec"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_javax.crypto.spec.html">javax.crypto.spec</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" CLASS="TableRowColor">
  <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="25%">
  <A NAME="org.json"></A>
  <nobr><A HREF="pkg_org.json.html">org.json</A></nobr>
  </TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
&nbsp;
<!-- End of API section -->
<!-- Start of packages section -->
  </div>    
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="copyright">
    Except as noted, this content is licensed under 
    <a href="//creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/"> Creative Commons Attribution 2.5</a>.
    For details and restrictions, see the <a href="/license.html">Content License</a>.
    </div>
  <div id="footerlinks">
  <p>
    <a href="//www.android.com/terms.html">Site Terms of Service</a> -
    <a href="//www.android.com/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> -
    <a href="//www.android.com/branding.html">Brand Guidelines</a>
  </p>
</div>
</div> <!-- end footer -->
</div><!-- end doc-content -->
</div> <!-- end body-content --> 
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-5831155-1");
pageTracker._setAllowAnchor(true);
pageTracker._initData();
pageTracker._trackPageview();
  } catch(e) {}
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(input)
#print(soup.prettify())

hits=soup.find_all("TABLE")
for ahit in hits:
    print ahit
```

Empty!! If I ask for tags such as 'nobr', 'head' etc. I do get the desired results back. Weird huh, and a bit frustrating!

Comment: Thanks.. it was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags in HTML are case-insensitive; the HTML parser lowercases them all and you need to *search* for them in lowercase:

```
hits = soup.find_all('table')
```

Demo:

```
>>> len(soup.find_all('TABLE'))
0
>>> len(soup.find_all('table'))
4
>>> soup.find('table')
<table class="diffspectable">
<tr>
<td class="diffspechead" colspan="2">API Diff Specification</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="diffspec" style="padding-top:.25em">To Level:</td>
<td class="diffvaluenew" style="padding-top:.25em">19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="diffspec">From Level:</td>
<td class="diffvalueold">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="diffspec">Generated</td>
<td class="diffvalue">2013.10.29 16:44</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ya gotta be kiddin' me!! I hadn't exclusively dealt with html before. Got me spinning for quite a while.Thanks a lot !